# Why does adding fields to ApplicationUser require Update-Database to be called?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am adding custom fields to ApplicationUser in my MVC 5 app. I am finding this class to be very confusing because it seems to be special in nasty ways.

My database initializer inherits `System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ApplicationDbContext>`.

Whenever I add a new field to one of my own Models, I do not have to create a migration and update-database to get the new field to show up in my database schema. I just press run.

HOWEVER, when I add a new field to ApplicationUser, every tutorial (for instance, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx) says that I should `enable-migration`, `add-migration "some name"`, and call `update-database`. This step seems necessary, because I have added fields to ApplicationUser without doing them, and my database schema isn't updated.

I don't understand why I need to do this for ApplicationUser and not for my own models. Can someone please explain?

Comment: is applicationUser in a different dbcontext? are you using migrations, and are automatic migrations turned on?

Comment: if I'm blowing away the database every time I start my project, I don't understand why I need migrations at all.

Comment: You don't, I was just trying to clarify your setup. So ApplicationDbContext is your only context and ApplicationUser is used in that context?

Comment: If you are using ApplicationDbContext only and specify your tables in it, then a change in any of these models (and thus, tables) will force you to update. Could you please provide some code?